# Check is HashMap contains another HashMap with specific value in Java

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, contains

I have a HashMap like this:

```java
private HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Material>> logs = new HashMap<>();
```

Then I have multiple Materials stored as enum (for example. `Material.OAK_LOG`).

Is there any easy way to check if HashMap `logs` contains HashMap with specific Material?

I came up with this, which works, but I want to know if there is any other way to do this without looping through the entire HashMap

```java
private boolean hasLog(Material mat){
    boolean contains = false;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<String, Material>> entry : this.logs.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue().containsValue(mat)){
            contains = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return contains;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to loop through the maps, doing sequential search.

You can simplify the logic a little by using `values()` instead of `entrySet()`, and simply `return` directly, but that's just minor refactoring:

```java
private boolean hasLog(Material mat) {
    for (HashMap<String, Material> submap : this.logs.values())
        if (submap.containsValue(mat))
            returns true;
    return false;
}
```

You can write the same logic using Java 8+ Streams, but it is the same nested loop sequential search, so runtime complexity remains *O(nm)*.

```java
private boolean hasLog(Material mat) {
    return this.logs.values().stream()
            .anyMatch(submap -> submap.containsValue(mat));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Material` objects are immutable and unique from an `equals` perspective, you could use them as a key in a cross reference map.  But if Material will change, your maps could get corrupted depending on how equals is set up.

```
Map<Material, String> crossRef = new HashMap<>();
```

Whenever you add a new Map with a material to logs, do the following:

```
int outerKey; = ... // some integer to get the inner map
String innerKey = .. // some string to get the actual Material
Map<String, Material> innerMap = logs.get(outerKey);
Material mat = new Material(...);
innerMap.put(innerKey, mat);
crossRef.put(mat, outerKey+"_"+innerKey);
```

Then later

```
if (crossRef.contains(mat)) {
   // it exists somewhere.
   String mapId = crossRef.get(mat);
   key[] parts = mapId.split("_");
   int outerKey = Integer.valueOf(parts[0]);
   String innerKey = parts[1];
   Map<String, Material> map = logs.get(outerKey);
   Material mat = map.get(innerKey);
}
```

One other downside is that your speeding up lookup time at the cost of more storage.

And to re-emphasize if two different Material objects compare equally they will be considered duplicates and thus cannot be used as keys to access both types of material.

Instead of using a concatenated String as the cross-ref key you could use a simple `class` or `record` that holds those as their specific type.

This was a drawn out answer to a simple question but it may provide some alternative ideas as to how to address your problem.